# Flutter chat application is not showing the first messages

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, chat

I am having trouble with chat messages. The first time chat messages do not appear. It needs to get out and rebuild the screen to get the messages. Messages are stored and retrieved from Firestore.

Only the very first messages do not appear instantly. After that (once out and back to chat screen) messages pop up without delay. How can I fix this error?

My Chat screen widget:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
SizeConfig().init(context);
double imageSize = SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical !* 6.5;
double imageSize1 = SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical! * 2.5;
double marginSearch = SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal !* 5;

debugPrint('${widget.senderId}, ${widget.receiverId}, $chatId, ${widget.chatId}');

return WillPopScope(
    child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: ConstantColors.bgColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: ConstantColors.bgColor,
        title: getTitleTexts(receiver!.name ?? ""),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 2,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          color: textColor,
          onPressed: () {
            finish();
          },
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: ()=> showMenu(
                context: context,
                position: const RelativeRect.fromLTRB(100, 0, 0, 0),
                items: [
                  PopupMenuItem(
                    value: 1,
                    child: Text(Languages.of(context)!.deleteChat),
                    onTap: () async {
                      await ServerAPI().chatsCollection.doc(widget.chatId).delete();
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                  ),
                  PopupMenuItem(
                    value: 2,
                    child: Text(Languages.of(context)!.blockUser),
                    onTap: () async {
                      await ServerAPI().usersCollection.doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).update({
                        "blockedId": FieldValue.arrayUnion([receiver!.id])
                      });
                      await ServerAPI().usersCollection.doc(receiver!.id).update({
                        "blockedBy": FieldValue.arrayUnion([FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid])
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  PopupMenuItem(
                    value: 3,
                    child: Text(Languages.of(context)!.reportUser),
                    onTap: () async {
                      await ServerAPI().usersCollection.doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).update({
                        "reportId": FieldValue.arrayUnion([receiver!.id])
                      });
                      await ServerAPI().usersCollection.doc(receiver!.id).update({
                        "reportBy": FieldValue.arrayUnion([FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid])
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
                elevation: 8.0,
              ),
              icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz, color: primaryTextColor,)
          )
        ],
      ),
    body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: marginSearch,
                  right: marginSearch,
                  bottom: marginSearch),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                      height: imageSize,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: cardColor,
                          boxShadow: const [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.black12,
                              offset: Offset(1, 1),
                              blurRadius: 1,
                            )
                          ],
                          borderRadius:
                          const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
                      child: TextField(
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          setState(() {
                            searchWord = val;
                          });
                        },
                        maxLines: 1,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: Constants.fontsFamily,
                            color: primaryTextColor,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            fontSize: Constants.getPercentSize(imageSize, 30)),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: Languages.of(context)!.searchHere,
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: Constants.fontsFamily,
                              color: primaryTextColor,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              fontSize: Constants.getPercentSize(imageSize, 30)),
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          contentPadding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3, left: 8),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      height: imageSize,
                      width: imageSize,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: primaryColor,
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Center(
                            child: Icon(Icons.search, color: whiteColor,
                              size: imageSize1,
                            )),
                        onTap: () {
                          searchWord != null ?
                              setState((){
                          stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chats')
                          .doc(widget.chatId).collection('messages')
                              .where('text', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: searchWord)
                          .orderBy('text', descending: true)
                              .orderBy('time', descending: true).snapshots();
                              })
                              : Container();
                        },
                      )
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: stream!,
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    List messages = snapshot.data.docs;
                    return ListView.builder(
                      controller: ScrollController(),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                      itemCount: messages.length,
                      reverse: true,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        MessageModel message = MessageModel.fromJson(messages.reversed.toList()[index].data());
                        return ChatBubble(msg: message);
                      },
                    );
                  } else {
                    //return uploadFirstMsg();
                    return Center(
                        child: Column(
                            children: [
                          Icon(Icons.question_mark_outlined, color: iconColor, size: 100),
                              Text(Languages.of(context)!.noData)
                        ])
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
            _buildMessageComposer(),
          ],
        ),
      )
    ),
    onWillPop: () async {
      finish();
      return false;
    }
    );
}
```

Comment: Use the sort method from Firebase and add which property should be sort by

Comment: my initial stream is 
    stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chats')
        .doc(widget.chatId).collection('messages')
        .orderBy('time', descending: false).snapshots();
by sort you mean orderBy(), right?